# Can I test MarkLogic SJS from mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, marklogic, marklogic-8

I would like to setup some javascript tests that include MarkLogic server-side javascript functions (like `xmdp.httpPost()` etc using `mocha.js`. It is doing some checks on the database and then posts something to an external service from within the MarkLogic backend.)

I run some tests already from `mocha.js` that checks all API REST calls. That works great, so now I want to include some tests from mocha that test some internal SJS code.

The SJS code lives in a module that is deployed with Roxy, but I have no clue how to access that module from mocha.js. Would the node.js marklogic.js library work? That is only for document search and querying afaik ?

How can it be done?

hugo

Answer (score 0):

Hugo, I don't think you can directly test SJS code from Mocha, but since you mentioned Roxy, you can write SJS unit tests with the [Roxy Unit Tester](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/wiki/Unit-Testing).